# Configuring RHEL 6.6 repositories

Tags: rhel6

I've been given a RHEL 6.6 system which seems poorly configured - there is no `subscription-manager` tool available and network access has been restricted upstream.

I was able to obtain outbound HTTPS connectivity but no FTP (don't ask).

How do I configure the `rhel-source.repo` file so that it can pull packages from a HTTPS mirror instead of ftp?

At the moment `baseurl` points at:

```
baseurl=ftp://ftp.redhat.com/pub/redhat/linux/enterprise/$releasever/en/os/SRPMS/
```

Ideally I'd like to point to https://?.redhat.com/...? but I can't find a list of repositories around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might have been subscribed with the old style `rhn_register`. Or it might not have been subscribed at all, in which case `yum` won't work. In either case, if you need source RPMs for RHEL 6 you can log in to your Red Hat account and download them manually in addition to FTP.

Note that [RHN is going away](https://access.redhat.com/rhn-to-rhsm) and you need to [migrate the system to Subscription Management](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/129723).